# If I build a blog, can I do it without having build an authentication system? MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, authentication, blogs, passport.js, mean

I am building a blog and I want to the be the only one that has the ability to create, read, update, destroy. Can I do this without having an authentication system? I am working with the MEAN stack and don't want to use passport just to have me as a user.

Comment: You could use your IP to show the additional features

Comment: Additional features?

Comment: Create update destroy

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: Pseudocode: if is_me()[which cheks on IP or whatever you choose] : show_button_create()